# htaccess rewrite rules are not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect my page from /index.php to /index?action=login but my .htaccess file is not working. I checked with

> a2enmod rewrite

it returned

> Module rewrite already enabled

I wrote a simple expression to redirect from index.php to index. But this is even not working

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^index/$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

I can't understand the mistake I was doing thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride All` directive set to read your .htaccess file?

Comment: I am not sure of it but there are some other htaccess files in other directory( localhost of a open source) and all those are working

Comment: It's still possible that it can be set to only allow certain directives inside htaccess.  Just a thought.. that's the first thing I would try and rule out.

Comment: can you specify path to file where I should add "AllowOverride All" thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect `/index.php` to `/index.php?action=login` you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?action=login [L,R=301]
```

The RewriteCondition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` checks to see if there is no query string in the old uri . Otherwise without the condition you will get a redirect loop error since both the old and the destination uri are identical.

Comment: Thanks @starkeen. this solved my issue. But I am not using .htaccess in root directory is there any way to set the base directory as current directory in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

With this rule you redirect from /login to /index.php?action=login